# Creating a template for Drupal 7 taxonomy term (page--taxonomy-term.php) strips page of CSS?

Tags: php, css, drupal

I've uploaded a custom layout for all of my Drupal taxonomy term pages (page--taxonomy-term.php). While the layout is extremely similar to all other pages (the only difference is that i've removed share buttons from taxonomy list pages), for some reason the page appears without any of my graphics or CSS (Even though my page--taxonomy-term.php file is almost identical to my page.tpl.php file).

Anyone know why this might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a part of the extension. Try correcting this

```
page--taxonomy-term.php
```

to this

```
page--taxonomy-term.tpl.php
```

Notice the extra addition of `.tpl` in the filename.

Also, Drupal is using a template called [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7) for displaying taxonomy terms. So it is possible that you will have to rename you current template to that in order to get it working.

Comment: I've changed the template name to: page--taxonomy-term.tpl.php, and nothing changes :( When I change it to: page--taxonomy--term--5.tpl.php, the page changes, but strips my CSS again.

Comment: Did you clear caches after changing template files? Also, did you copy the original `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` to your theme directory and add your modifications in that?